# `using my_type = unsigned;` vs `using my_type = unsigned int;` in C++

Tags: unsigned, unsigned-integer

In C++, are the following two code snippets equivalent?

```cpp
    using my_type = unsigned;
    my_type variable;
```

and

```cpp
    using my_type = unsigned int;
    my_type variable;
```

If they are, why bother defining `my_type` instead of using `unsigned` or even `unsigned int`? Considering the latter two are a bit longer, but more explicit, when would one define and use `my_type`, `unsigned` and/or `unsigned int`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they are identical. Using `my_type` can make the intention clearer. E.g. consider `using celsius = int;`

To get even better type safety you can use the newtype pattern (Google it) but it is a bit tedious in C++.

The choice of `unsigned` Vs `unsigned int` is just taste.

Comment: Giving it a separate name also gives you the chance to alter the type later. For example, if you realize that `unsigned` was too small, you can change it to `using my_type = unsigned long;`.